# Cascade DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a cascade DropDownList, but in the second dropdown when I post data to controller the valeu property in the object that my action receives is null, and I dont know why.

My controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ListaEstados(String id)
{
    var estados = Util.getEstados(id); 
    return Json(estados);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddCidade(Cidade c)
{
    c.Cadastrar(c);
    return RedirectToAction("AddCidade");
}
```

My View

```
 @model Projeto_P1.Models.Cidade
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Cadastro de Cidades";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddCidade", "Geral", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="container">
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                @Html.Label("Cidade")
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.Label("País")
                @Html.DropDownList("Pais", (SelectList)ViewData["paises"], "Selecione", new { id = "PaisID"})
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.Label("Estado")
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Estado, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Selecione")
            </div>

            <br />

            <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#PaisID").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "ListaEstados",
                type: 'POST',
                data: { ID: $(this).val() },
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var elements = "";
                    $.each(data, function () {
                        elements = elements + '<option values="' + this.ID + '">' + this.Nome + '</option>'
                    })
                    $('#Estado').empty().attr('disabled', false).append(elements);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive solved my problem, there is a S in ajax code, I have´t seen it: `elements = elements + '<option values="' + this.ID..`.
I took it and it worked.